# Find out which Zend Framework module loads CPU up to 200%

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, cpu-usage

In my Cpanel account in Daily Process Log I can see that my zend framework application load CPU very much

```
Top Process %CPU 182 /usr/bin/php /home/*******/public_html/index.php
```

But any requests to ZF application goes by index.php (with rewrite rule for Apache)
Is it possible to find out what request (url) load CPU?

Comment: @TimStone Well, if you have 2 CPUs, and each is loaded to 100%, then you have 200%.

Comment: I understand why cpu-usage is more than 100%. I need to know what request cause it. Just filename is not enough for me - apache rewrite throw all requests to imdex.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps:

ZFDebug - a debug bar for Zend Framework
http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/

Comment: ZFDebud doesn't help - I don't know what module load CPU. In most cases that load means that request to server is incorrect. 
For example I got high load when site was under XSS atack and requests to server was cp1251 encoded (ZF use UTF8) - filtering inputs data takes some minutes for standart zend filters to parse wrong-encoded data. 
So first task is to find which request makes the problen. After this I can use zend_deruger or ZFdebug bar to fix it.

Comment: And in cpanel I have this information but it shows me path to script that is always the same.
Also i can accept time of load, than I can find unusual request in apache logs